# Need a help with Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

We have Markov Chain with continuous time, three conditiions and generator: 
\begin{equation*}
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 2\\
1 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Initial distribution $X_0=1$ almost sure. How to find the distribution of the second moment of the chain jump?

Comment: I found that p1=1/4; p2=1/4; p3=1/2. What should I do next?

Comment: So we need to find transition matrix then find a time of second jump?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the Kolmogorov forward and backward equations which govern the transient behavior of the process. In particular, we have
$$
P'(t) = QP(t),
$$
where $P_{ij}(t) = (\mathbb P(X(t) = j\mid X(0)=i)$. The solution to this differential equation is the matrix exponential $$P(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tQ)^n}{n!}. $$
In this case, one can use diagonalization to compute powers of $Q$, and we find that
$$
P(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{3 e^{-4 t}}{4}+\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}-\frac{e^{-4 t}}{4} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-4 t}}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{4}-\frac{e^{-4 t}}{4} & \frac{1}{12} \left(e^{-4 t}+8 e^{-t}+3\right) & \frac{1}{6} \left(e^{-4 t}-4 e^{-t}+3\right) \\
 \frac{1}{4}-\frac{e^{-4 t}}{4} & \frac{1}{12} \left(e^{-4 t}-4 e^{-t}+3\right) & \frac{1}{6} \left(e^{-4 t}+2 e^{-t}+3\right) \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Since $\mathbb P(X(0)=1)=1$, the distribution of the first jump is given by the minimum of two exponentially distributed random variables - namely, it is exponential with rate $3$. To analyze the distribution of the second jump, we must condition on the first jump. Let $\{J_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ denote the jump chain. Then $J_2$ is the sum of $J_1$ and a hyperexponential distribution:
\begin{align}
J_2 = J_1 + Y
\end{align}
where
$$
f_Y(t) = \frac13 e^{-t}+\frac23 e^{-t} = e^{-t},
$$
which in this case happens to be exponential as well. We compute the density of $J_2$ by convolution:
\begin{align}
f_{J_2}(t) &= f_{J_1}\star f_Y(t)\\
&= \int_0^t f_{J_1}(\tau) f_Y(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \int_0^t 3e^{-3\tau} e^{-(t-\tau)}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \frac32 e^{-3t}(e^{2t}-1).
\end{align}

Comment: Somewhere's we have trouble because $\lim_{t \to+\infty} f_{J_2}(t) = 0$. But i understand the idea